# Adding jQuery to looped divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops, while-loop

I have retrieved my data from mySQL using php. And the retrieved data is looped through so that every div has an id of "bills" +1 and "bills_info" +1.
I'm trying to add jquery to these divs so that some of text would be hidden until clicked upon. But since the divs are looped through and have different names, i would like to loop through the jquery too, so i would have to write the code as many times as there are divs.

Here is my code:

```
$i=0;
$j=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

   // Write the value of the column FirstName and BirthDate
  echo "<div data-role='main' id='bill" .$i++."' class='bills'>" . $row['BName'] . "</div>";

  echo "<div data-role='popup' id='bill_info" .$j++."' class='bill_info'><p>Account number: ". $row['AccNumb'] ."</p>
      <p> Reference Numebr: " . $row['RefNumb'] . "</p>
      <p> Amount: " . $row['Amount'] . "€</p>
      <p> Due date: " . $row['eDate'] . "</p></div>";

  }
```

Jquery:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

$(function() {

    $( '#bill_info' + j++ ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false
    });

    $("#bills" + i++).click(function() {
       $("#bill_info" + j++).dialog("open");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the dialogs you can use their class as selector and the plugin will initialize for all the elements with that class.

For the buttons(or whatever `#billsx` is) you can add a data attribute with the incremental number and also use class to add the click handler

```
<div data-role='main' data-id='bill_info" .$i++."' class='bills'>
```

JS

```
$('.bill_info').dialog({
   autoOpen: false
});

$('.bills').click(function(){
     var dialogId = $(this).data('id');
     $('#'+dialogId).dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! I tried your method but i still can't get the popups to work..

Comment: did you wrap the code above in `$(function(){ })`? Are errors thrown?

Comment: oops I mismatched the ID , missing the bill_info in the `data-id` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Target by class instead of id, and use `next()` top select the correct `bill_info` element instead:

```
$(function() {

    $('.bills').dialog({
    autoOpen: false
    });

    $('.bills').click(function() {
       $(this).next().dialog("open");
    });

});
```

Comment: next() not likely to work since dialogs get appended to body thereby changing DOM tree structure